# How to set the statusbar colour in specific page only using ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, statusbar

I am using create a mobile application for android using ionic 2.

I am making a status Bar background colour using [status bar plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/).But i would like to change the status bar colour in every page.

When i am using a following code in app.component.ts. But it reflect to the all page. How to achieve it?

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

 constructor(private statusBar:StatusBar){

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ff6d79');
     this.splashScreen.hide();
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On every page, you should set it individually.

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

export class HomePage {

  constructor(private statusBar:StatusBar){

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ff6d79');
  }

}
```

Comment: but it increase the code.another way to achive it in a common component ?

Comment: Yes, you could subscribe to the root NavController events and set it there.